# Unity Cardboard stop auto walk c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I did create a small game for Cardboard in Unity and did implement an Autowalk feature that works with CardboardTrigger and/or threshold. It works perfectly fine, but i need to add an "autostop" function. Therefore i want to create a Cube that Is Trigger to stop the player from walking if i walk into the Cube.

I tried something like :

```
OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider) {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "stop") 
    }

    {
        isWalking = false;
    }
```

But i am noob as you can see, and it doesn't work :-)
Can somebody help me? Would be very very nice!

The code for the auto walk feature is as the following, thanks to Jupp Otto:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Autowalk : MonoBehaviour 
{
private const int RIGHT_ANGLE = 90; 

// This variable determinates if the player will move or not 
private bool isWalking = false;

CardboardHead head = null;

//This is the variable for the player speed
[Tooltip("With this speed the player will move.")]
public float speed;

[Tooltip("Activate this checkbox if the player shall move when the Cardboard trigger is pulled.")]
public bool walkWhenTriggered;

[Tooltip("Activate this checkbox if the player shall move when he looks below the threshold.")]
public bool walkWhenLookDown;

[Tooltip("This has to be an angle from 0° to 90°")]
public double thresholdAngle;

[Tooltip("Activate this Checkbox if you want to freeze the y-coordiante for the player. " +
         "For example in the case of you have no collider attached to your CardboardMain-GameObject" +
         "and you want to stay in a fixed level.")]
public bool freezeYPosition; 

[Tooltip("This is the fixed y-coordinate.")]
public float yOffset;

void Start () 
{
    head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head;
}

void Update () 
{
    // Walk when the Cardboard Trigger is used 
    if (walkWhenTriggered && !walkWhenLookDown && !isWalking && Cardboard.SDK.Triggered) 
    {
        isWalking = true;
    } 
    else if (walkWhenTriggered && !walkWhenLookDown && isWalking && Cardboard.SDK.Triggered) 
    {
        isWalking = false;
    }

    // Walk when player looks below the threshold angle 
    if (walkWhenLookDown && !walkWhenTriggered && !isWalking &&  
        head.transform.eulerAngles.x >= thresholdAngle && 
        head.transform.eulerAngles.x <= RIGHT_ANGLE) 
    {
        isWalking = true;
    } 
    else if (walkWhenLookDown && !walkWhenTriggered && isWalking && 
             (head.transform.eulerAngles.x <= thresholdAngle ||
             head.transform.eulerAngles.x >= RIGHT_ANGLE)) 
    {
        isWalking = false;
    }

    // Walk when the Cardboard trigger is used and the player looks down below the threshold angle
    if (walkWhenLookDown && walkWhenTriggered && !isWalking &&  
        head.transform.eulerAngles.x >= thresholdAngle && 
        Cardboard.SDK.Triggered &&
        head.transform.eulerAngles.x <= RIGHT_ANGLE) 
    {
        isWalking = true;
    } 
    else if (walkWhenLookDown && walkWhenTriggered && isWalking && 
             head.transform.eulerAngles.x >= thresholdAngle &&
             (Cardboard.SDK.Triggered || 
             head.transform.eulerAngles.x >= RIGHT_ANGLE)) 
    {
        isWalking = false;
    }

    if (isWalking) 
    {
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(head.transform.forward.x, 0, head.transform.forward.z).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, -transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0));
        transform.Translate(rotation * direction);
    }

    if(freezeYPosition)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, yOffset, transform.position.z);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks a lot and have a nice weekend,
B.

Comment: @maxhb Actually I think the [tag:unity3d] tag is more relevant than the [tag:google-cardboard] tag.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I wanted to add a unity3 tag, too. but I was not sure which tag was the best matching one.

Comment: thanks to both of you!